# array_slice but for images php

Tags: php, arrays, image, slice

i have written this code

```
  <?php
        $a = Meme::all();
        $b = count($a);
        for($i=$b;$i<$b-3;$i--)  {
    ?>      <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $a[$i]->path; ?>" /> </div>
    <?php
    }?>
```

i want to output the last 3 memes(images) but this for loop doesn't work. So i found something that is called array_slice and i wanted to use it but everyone was using print_r but in this case i don't need it. So any suggestions?

Comment: _...the last 3 memes(images)_ do you mean the last 3 elements of `$a`?

Comment: yes. basically a is an array from which i have a column path that i put it in img src to get the image

Comment: So what exactly isn't working with the `for`-Loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store those 3 elements of array `$a` in a new array `$b` by using `array_slice`:

```
<?php    
    $a = Meme::all();
    $b = array_slice($a, 3);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
?>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $b[$i]->path; ?>" /> </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as this :

```
$nb = 3;

$a = [1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 3 => 'john', 4 => 'doe', 5 => 'test'];
$b = count($a);
$results = array_slice($a, $b-$nb, $nb);

foreach($result AS $k => $result) {
    echo '<p>'.$result.'</p>';
}
```

[Also see this snippet here in action](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f2063694199de40937f5fb9c65f262c9a6b2be60).

> Explanations : You use array_slice with first param being your array.
>   The second if the offset, i.e. the starting key of your array.

Answer (score 0):

[FWIW](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-what-it-s-worth) I have provided another alternative:

```php
<?php
$a = Meme::all();
$b = count($a);
$toShow = 3; // how many elements to display

for ($i = $b - $toShow; $i < $b; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo $a[$i]->path; ?>" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

It is slightly faster than the accepted solution.
Something else to note is that if the array is not a multiple of 3 then the corrected solution will throw an error since the splice will not return an array with the length of 3. <sub>Naturally, if `$toShow` is greater than or equal to the `count($a)` this will also throw an error.</sub>